# What does this Apache FOP error mean?

Tags: pdf, xslt, pdf-generation, apache-fop

Error message

> (Location of error
>   unknown)org.apache.fop.fo.Validation
>   Exception: Property id "_Ref191196753"
>   previously used; id values  must be
>   unique in document.

Any ideas on what may cause this? Is it because I have a for-each and apply the same template multiple times?

Comment: I took the liberty of rearranging the question a bit, moved the error message into the question body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#id) states the id of an element must be unique.

The following code produces the error message you get.

```
<fo:block id="_Ref191196753"/>
<fo:block id="_Ref191196753"/>
```

You need to search your fo-file to locate the occurences of the elements with the same id. Then make changes in your XSLT to eliminate these.

Comment: @Ayrad: For example, it could be an `fo:block` with a hard-coded id in an `xsl:for-each` loop or an `xsl:template` that gets applied more than once.

Comment: You may be able to use the XSLT "generate-id" function to come up with unique ids, if that's what you need.